# Download JSON object as JSON file (Android/Javascript/WebApp)

Tags: javascript, android, json, web-applications, download

I would like to download a JSON object as a JSON file and save it to the local file system of Android and IOS devices with Javascript.

For Desktop Browser the solution would be the following:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(MyJSONobject);    
var url = 'data:text/json;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
window.open(url, '_blank');
window.focus();
```

Or with the [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) simply:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(MyJSONobject);    
var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/json"});
saveAs(blob, "helloworld.json");
```

But this is not working for Android Browser. I would like to save the json object as json file to the downloads directory at the android device. How to do that?

**Addition:**
Im using this in a Web application. The JSON object will be created by my WebApp. When the user clicks a button then this JSON object should be saved as JSON file to the file system of the users device. For Andorid Versions below 4.4 the two methods mentioned above are not working.

Comment: Are you looking for a JavaScript answer to use in a Cordova/Phonegap app, or native solutions for iOS and Android?

Comment: If there is a native solution that would be awesome. Similar to my first example. Just a simple download. But if there is nothing like that than Cordova would be fine. But i dont have any idea yet how to use Cordova.

Comment: Ah sorry maby I misunderstood your question. Its a webapp. The json object is created from the webapp. I want to download this json object as json file to the users device when the user is clicking a button.

Comment: Aah, I see. So `window.open` doesn't open a new window/tab in Chrome or Safari mobile?

Comment: window.open(url, '_blank'); is working fine. Maybe its the window.focus() that is not working. At least at the android browser of my smartphone (Android 4.3).

Comment: Not surprised that window.focus doesn't work. Just tried the FileSaver demo you linked and it works on Android for me (4.4) - how about you?

Comment: The filesaver demo works fine at my tablet (android 4.4). But it does not work on my smartphone (android 4.3)

Comment: The readme of filesaver is not mentioning android browser as suportet browser too. For some older browser the readme says that you have to use Data:URL as constructor instead of Blob. How to do that?

Comment: It doesn't list Android browser but it does list Chrome for Android (with no specific version). Since it lists Safari 6.1, I imagine if it doesn't list Android browser then it isn't supported :(

Comment: So whats the alternative. How to do that for Android Browsers < 4.4

Comment: You may have to accept that it's not possible using client side code only. You could instead have a server side script that takes a JSON string as a URL parameter and serves it as a file using `content-disposition: attachment`. You could then use JavaScript's `window.location` to point the user there. As the file is served as a download ("attachment") most browsers will keep the user's current page open. It's hacky, but it might just work. If that sounds like something you'd consider I can write you up an answer.

Comment: That would be awesome if you could to that! I would be thankful for that.